# How Can i use log4php inside exec()

Tags: php, logging, log4php

for logging purpose i am using the following code

```
$logFile = __DIR__ . "/log/scheduler_logs\_log.txt";
        print_r($logFile);
        mkdir(dirname($logFile), "0777", true);
        chmod("{$logFile}", 0777);
        dirname($logFile) ? exec("($command) > $logFile") : exec("$command");
```

Instead of these can i use log4php..i tried a simple program but i am not sure that i can use that inside exec().

```
 `include_once "MyLogger.php";
  $loggerinfo = LoggingInfo::getInstantLogger("myfolderpath");`
```

Mylogger.php

```
  public static function getInstantLogger($path) {

        Logger::configure(array(
            'rootLogger' => array(
                'appenders' => array('AppenderSkeleton'),
            ),
            'appenders' => array(
                'AppenderSkeleton' => array(
                    'class' => 'LoggerAppenderDailyFile',
                    'layout' => array(
                        'class' => 'LoggerLayoutPattern',
                        'params' => array(
                            'conversionPattern' => '%date [%logger] %message%newline'
                        )
                    ),
                    'params' => array(
                        'file' =>  "./logs/$path/".gmdate('Y-m-d\Th:i:s'). '.log',
                        'append' => true,
                        'datePattern' => gmdate('Y-m-d')
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
        return Logger::getRootLogger(); }
```

Comment: so you need to execute some php script in exec using php script ? why

Comment: for some automation process and all

Comment: how can i get all my echo statements in a log file using log4php

Comment: what's the `$command` ? and what's the error you are getting?

Comment: $command = php myfile.php, 
log file creation is not happening

Comment: how do you exec your log4php? put this `include_once "MyLogger.php";
  $loggerinfo = LoggingInfo::getInstantLogger("myfolderpath");` in a new file and try to execute `php file.php`

Comment: log4php ships with an appender for echo , **[see here](https://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appenders/echo.html)**